# How does the size of a valve opening determine liquid velocity and pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity, fluid-statics, flow

Say we have a water reservoir with a valve near the bottom to allow water to be released into a separate reservoir (for example, in order to avoid flooding). The valve is initially slightly (10%) open, and they want to open the valve to 20%. What effects will this have on the valve and on the water traveling through it? Specifically, how will it affect the fluid velocity and mass flow rate, and the pressure on the valve?

Comment: What type of valve is it?  Is it a gate valve or some type of control valve?

Comment: It is a gate valve

Comment: If you're lucky, the gate valve manufacturer will have information regarding flow rate vs. valve position for various delta-P curves.  Contact the manufacturer first, then go to much more effort if you can't get the information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of valve. Butterfly valves for example have a approximately linear behaviour only at a few percent of opening. Gate valves are more linear.

But for small openings as 10% to 20%, an almost linear behaviour is expected. That means the flow doubles, provided the volume of the reservoir is big enough to have its level practically constant.